# How to see programs installed in ProgramFiles(x86) directory in Control Panel on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

On my PC, which is 64-bit Windows 7, under control panel, programs and features, I can see programs only installed under `ProgramFiles` directory and not programs installed under `ProgramFiles(x86)`.
How can see these programs so that I can uninstall programs from this directory?

Comment: Isn't happening on my Windows 8 system. Have you installed anything recently or changed any setting on your system, if you may remember?

Comment: @Mohit No, not as far as I can remember...

Comment: Can it be a case that the program you have installed in x86 folder isn't installed properly? Try reinstalling that program and see if it appears in "Programs and Features".

Comment: @Mohit I don't see any program installed in ProgramFiles(x86),I have installed many programs there.

Comment: Unless your x86 programs are installed on another drive and Windows can't see it somehow, this is exceedingly weird. Something sounds broken. Maybe your x64 Windows is acting like a 32-bit version for some reason, and just does not know a x86 folder is supposed to exist. I have a feeling you won't be able to find any fix for this... Apart from moving all installed apps to Program Files, but this is just running away from the problem. I suggest you try to run a Windows repair, or even format, eventually. >.<"

Answer (score -1):

Follow the usual procedure for choosing which program to use.
Select "Browse" and navigate to c\program files
Now click the "Previous locations" button at the end of the line.
Highlight "Program files " then add (x86) to the name.
Enter , and you should see all the required program files.
Select the one you want to use.

Comment: Where should I look for that *Browse* button?